# The displayed font text is too high

Tags: fonts, gui

I'm not sure if I didn't dig enough posts about this problem. But here's the thing, I noticed that the text are suddenly a bit too high like a CSS property line-height is at 105%.

I wonder if anyone could point me to a guide/documentation to put the font in their normal range. Thanks.

Note: All of the text including installed apps, and system are affected by this small issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There are two possibilities:*

1. You might have turned on large text under Universal Access.

   **Open Settings> Universal Access > Uncheck Large Text**.
2. You can adjust font size via GNOME Tweaks.

   **Open GNOME Tweaks > Fonts.**

Comment: Hi. Nice catch! Thought I missed that possibility. It turns out the font I used isn't that friendly much with the system. I figured using other fonts aside from Ubuntu font causes this misalignment. Do you have any recommendation to find an appropriate way to install custom fonts? Thanks for answering. Kudos!